# Link not routing to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, react-router

When I click on a link, it will update the URL properly. However, the component associated with that route will not appear on screen.

index.js:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

App.js:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>
        React Router Tester
      </h1>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/Home" component = {Home}/>
      </Routes>

      <Link to="/Home">
      Test
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `react-router-dom` API has changed in the latest versions.

Instead of

```
<Route path="/Home" component={Home} />
```

use

```
<Route path="/Home" element={<Home />} />
```

Comment: @Ancross, check this out !!